# Elastic Beanstalk Java Web application war file deployed then URL saying Proxy Error

Tags: proxy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image: 502 proxy error]
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Comment: If i'm not using databse then its working fine but when using       using aws -rds-mysql data base then its showing me above error. I was deployed it in tomcat server using elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

This helps me :

1.Sign into AWS Console.

2.Go to EC2 Services.

3. On the left panel, click on the Load Balancing
4. Load Balancers.
   In the top panel, select the Load Balancer for which you want to change the idle timeout.

5.Now in the bottom panel, under the ‘Attributes’ section, click on the ‘Edit idle timeout’ button.

6. The default value would be 60 seconds. Change it to the value that you would like (say, 180 seconds).

7.Click on the ‘Save’ button.

For more detail you can refer following links :

https://dzone.com/articles/aws-elastic-beanstalk-timeouts-a-detective-story

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html